# Is the first eigenvalue of a parabolic ends of a Riemanian manifold 0? 

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Is the first eigenvalue of a parabolic ends of a Riemanian manifold 0?

Answer (score 1):

If a manifold is parabolic, then 0 belongs to the spectrum of the Laplacian. A very good survey of the whole area is [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1999-36-02/S0273-0979-99-00776-4/S0273-0979-99-00776-4.pdf) paper of Grigor'yan.